# Firebase push() function throws .child() is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm quite new to working with firebase. I am looking at a way to push data to a list in firebase firestore.

My desired outcome is as in the image below. When there is a new transaction, I need to push that to "packageTransactions" with a new ID. I read in Documentation that the ID can be auto generated and it is derived from timestamp. This would be perfect for me since then ordering is easy.;
[image: Desired Outcome]

I tried achieving this in two ways;

**Method 1:**

```
return firebase.firestore()
    .collection('packages')
    .doc(`${parcelId}`)
    .child("packageTransactions")
    .push()
    .set({"userId": user.uid, "transactionTime": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")})
```

This generates error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: firebase.firestore().collection('packages').doc("" + parcelId).child is not a function. (In 'firebase.firestore().collection('packages').doc("" + parcelId).child("packageTransactions")', 'firebase.firestore().collection('packages').doc("" + parcelId).child' is undefined)]

**Method 2:**

```
var db= firebase.firestore();
var ref = db.ref(`packages/${parcelId}/`);
var transactRef = ref.child("packageTransactions");

transactRef.push().set({
  "userId": user.uid, 
  "transactionTime": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
})
```

This generates error:*

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: db.ref is not a function. (In 'db.ref("packages/" + parcelId + "/")', 'db.ref' is undefined)

[image: Code]

The updateCarrier function in the image works. I'm having trouble with pushCurrentHolder function.

Highly appreciate if anyone can help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up Realtime Database and Firestore API. They are not the same database and have completely different APIs.

There is no `push()` method in Firestore.  There is also no `child()` method.  As such, this code is doesn't make any sense:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection('packages')
    .doc(`${parcelId}`)
    .child("packageTransactions")
    .push()
    .set({"userId": user.uid, "transactionTime": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")})
```

If you want to add a document to the packages collection with a random ID, do this instead:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection('packages')
    .doc(parcelId)
    .add({"userId": user.uid, "transactionTime": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")})
```

I'm sure this will not do exactly what you want, but you can see how the API works.

I strongly suggest reviewing the [Firestore documentation for writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) in order to understand the APIs better.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing between firebase realtime database and firestore, there is no `child()` method in firestore:

```
var db= firebase.firestore();
var ref = db.collection("packages").doc(`${parcelId}`);
var transactRef = ref.collection("packageTransactions");
transactRef.add({
  "userId": user.uid, 
  "transactionTime": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
})
```

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web

Answer (score 1):

Both `firestore` & `realtime` APIs aren't the same. You are mixing up the methods of both the APIs. The `push()` & `child()` methods are of `realtime` API not `firestore`. To achieve what you want, do:

```js
const db = firebase.firestore()

let transactRef = db.collection("packages")
                    .doc(parcelId)
                    .collection("packageTransactions")

transactRef.add({
  userId: user.uid,
  transactionTime: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
})
```